# fastboot not finding SPH-L720 on Linux

Tags: linux, samsung-galaxy-s-4, fastboot

This is with Ubuntu 13.10 on the host and a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S4 SPH-L720.

When in normal mode, 'adb devices' finds my phone.

I do 'adb reboot bootloader' to reboot my phone into bootloader mode.

'fastboot devices' comes back empty. 'sudo fastboot devices' also comes back empty.

I have setup the udev rules file accordingly (replaced my real login with myuser)

```
~  cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules     
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="myuser"
```

lsusb returns the following (fyi, the device is an S4, not an S2)

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
```

I've read a ton of articles on this and I can't get this working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that the S4 has a fastboot mode. Typically you would flash Samsung devices with [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2189539).

Comment: I believe it's called download mode, but it definitely has it. This probably differs on the different carrier variants.

Comment: I know about download mode, that's what Odin is for. I believe that's *different* from a fastboot mode, though. For example, my old Galaxy Nexus had **both** modes, but I think that was because it was a Nexus device. I don't think that carrier branded Samsung phones typically have a way to use fastboot.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with fastboot, there's an alternative for Samsung phones called Heimdall. I used it on my SIII mini to install TWRP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to the answer to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122389/galaxy-s4-mini-not-recognized-by-linux-in-download-mode) question, Samsung devices do not support fastboot.
[This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2402631) thread on XDA Forums states the same.